# Check if a file exists in a linux script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

i made a linux script which receives as first argument a path to a directory. I don't know the path. And i want to check if "file.txt" exists at that certain path . For example :

```
if [ -e $1/file.txt ];then
       echo HAHA
fi
```

Comment: `[[ -f "$1/file.txt" ]] && echo "HAHA"` should work.

Comment: What you have should work as intended as long as `$1` doesn't contain any whitespace. Quoting it as `"$1/file.txt"` would take care of that problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
if [[ -e "$1/file.txt" ]]; then
       echo "It exists"
fi
```